# Can I retrieve google map data for traffic and whose the users?

Tags: google-maps, google, streets, traffic, user-account

Can I retrieve Google map data for traffic on a specific street?

Does the the data include attributes about the users who are creating the traffic (users age in the traffic, gender, etc.)?

Comment: Any ideas regarding my question?